# What's the rationale behind appending the userid to an answer share URL?

Tags: discussion, privacy

When I use the share feature to get an answer's URL, I have my userid appended.

(Yes, yes, I know it's mentioned, in tiny letters.)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/171256/1394353

But this works just as well and gets redirected to the same page:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/171256

The only difference is that the userid has been left off.

In fact, if I put in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/171256/999999

I still get to the same page.

It could be that I want to post a link to an answer in a forum, yet do not want it to be linked back to my Stack Overflow account. Which in my case is in my name. I suspect that this will be true for at least some of us who are logging in via Google.

The only discussion I saw about this is https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2787/remove-the-user-identifying-part-of-the-share-url

Now, I am not asking for a special feature (I'll just trim off my userid before posting the URL). I just don't get why it was considered important and a good idea to do this in the first place.

It's not like the privacy implications are immediately obvious when you paste some complicated alphanumeric URL somewhere.

Comment: Well there are some badges that depend on how much YOUR link is used, so I guess this is why? To help track how many time a specific link of yours is clicked on?

Comment: I get that.  Still "earning a badge", seems of very secondary importance to privacy considerations.  I guess that's my opinion. Did this predate the social network (Facebook, Google) login capability?

Comment: @JLPeyret well... what kind of privacy considerations? It's not like your userID is private... or if, using it, I can get ANY kind of private info from you... If you don't like your real name to be used... don't use it? I don't really see how much of an issue this is.. (although there is the very valid possibility I am missing something)

Comment: A total duplicate.  Somehow I did not find it while Googling, I only found the Math meta posting.

Comment: ok, because this is SO, I'm actually using my name.  I have different handles for other StackExchange, where I wouldn't want to mix professional concerns with recreational concerns.  That's a decision I thought about a bit and I took it.  Now, if I grab an answer here, and go post its url on another website, say recreational drug discussion forum, just to take something controversial, it's not an entirely happy outcome that I've somehow leaked user info, is it?

Comment: again... I don't see what is leaked? Your username.... I don't need a linked answer to find it... No matter how controversial your link.... it's not like the actual info gotten from said link is confidential... (and the solution to security through obfuscation is still there.. like just using your first name... or a completely made up handle). If your issue is that I could link YOUR profile to something you didn't agree to... then that's slightly different, no? Although I still fail to see how much of a problem this is...

Comment: ... isn' t the 'confidential information' still right there in the question/answer being linked to? The only difference would be that someone needs to click on the link to see it. If you don't want to spread information, don't post links to it!

Comment: OP's privacy concern is relevant. Say my SO account is my real name. And say I'm using a forum about drugs to which I connect with a username that does not identify me. If I post a link on that forum using the "share" feature, this link will include my SO user id, which identifies me. OK, anyone could have posted that link appending my user ID, but most likely I'm the one who did. There is the information leakage. Alright, this is advertised as it says "(includes your user id)" in the "share link" box, but I never noticed it before I got the Announcer badge and wondered about it.

Comment: What could be done about it is make it even clearer that the link includes the ID. Some (!) icon that would trigger a tooltip on click or hover, for instance. I'm wondering if there could be a way to cypher the username so that only SO can get back to the user. But I haven't given much thought to it.